# Modification of javascript inheritance framework

Tags: javascript

I've modified John Resig [simple javascript inheritance framework](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/), by adding set function with setter functionality. It seems that it works. Is it written correctly? Can you see some undesired behavior?
Framework:

```js
(function(){
   var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
   this.Class = function(){};
   Class.extend = function(prop) {
     var _super = this.prototype;
    initializing = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;
    for (var name in prop) {
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
        (function(name, fn){
          return function() {
            var tmp = this._super;
            this._super = _super[name];
            var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);       
            // CHANGED HERE FROM this._super = tmp;
            // don't like some not used properties 
            if(tmp)this._super = tmp;
            // END OF CHANGE
            return ret;
          };
        })(name, prop[name]) :
        prop[name];
    }
    function Class() {
      if ( !initializing && this.init )
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Class.prototype = prototype;
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    // CHANGED HERE
    // Set method
    Class.prototype.set = function(attrs) {
      for (var attr in attrs) {
        //if exist setter function this.on_change{key of wrap: function(key of wrap, new value)
        if(this.on_change[attr])this.on_change[attr].call(this,attr,attrs[attr]);
        else this[attr] = attrs[attr];
      }
      return this;
    };
    if(!Class.prototype.on_change)Class.prototype.on_change={};
    // END OF CHANGE

    return Class;
  };
})();
```

Test code:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  a: 15,
  b: 30,
  init: function(){
      //...
  },
  on_change:{
      b: function(oldKey, set){this[oldKey] = set*2}
  }
});
var p = new Person();
p.set({a:25,b:40});
```

Comment: Code like that is an anti pattern. It should be avoided by removing it.

Comment: Can you be please more specific. Very similar approach you can see in prototype.js or backbone.js. Extendable is also jquery object. Maybe there is more coupling on "on_change" object, but setter are placed inside the object. Code is dry and readable in my opinion.

Comment: I mean using setters and adding listeners to them. It's an anti pattern and should be avoided. There are a view use-cases for reactive programming but those are edge cases.

Comment: Two moths ago, I've started using Dart. There are native setters and getters. Look at solution of Dart team: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#fields-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 3):

Easy question first : *Is it written correctly?*

```
Class.prototype.set = function(attrs) {
  for (var attr in attrs) {
    //if exist setter function this.on_change{key of wrap: function(key of wrap, new value)
    if(this.on_change[attr])this.on_change[attr].call(this,attr,attrs[attr]);
    else this[attr] = attrs[attr];
  }
  return this;
};
if(!Class.prototype.on_change)Class.prototype.on_change={};
```

- `attrs` is not a good name, it does not contain a list of attributes, but a list of name/value pairs, I would suggest the Spartan `o` for Object or maybe `map`.
- Dropping the curly braces in your if statement is ok, dropping the newlines not so much
- The one line of comment is not very helpful :\
- You could use the following for initialization of `on_change` : 
  `Class.prototype.on_change = Class.prototype.on_change || {};`
- `on_change` is not lowerCamelCase -> `onChange` would be more idiomatic.

I would counter suggest:

```
Class.prototype.set = function( map ){
  for ( var attributeName in map ) {
    var value  = map[attributeName],
        setter = this.onChange[attributeName];
    if( setter )
      setter.call( this, attributeName, value );
    else 
      this[attributeName] = value;
  }
  return this;
};
Class.prototype.onChange = Class.prototype.onChange || {};
```

Hard question: *Can you see some undesired behavior?*

Yes.

1. Providing `onChange` is old skool, real events use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
2. There are now 2 ways to change a property, thru `set` and thru changing properties directly. The setter functions only work for `set`, this will introduce bugs.
3. You are counting on the setter to do the assignment,  another possible source of bugs. I would do the assignment regardless, rename `setter` to `listener` and then execute the listener:

   ```
   this[attributeName] = value;
   if( listener )
     listener.call( this, attributeName, value );
   ```

Comment: One nitpick: `o` is never a good name.

Comment: I would upgrade that nit-pick to one **GobSmacker**: *`o` is never a good name* !!

Comment: Disagreed : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/spartan-programming.html 'o' like 'i' and 's' are very often good names. I did provide an alternative for the faint of heart ;)